# "MoleculeFeatures" in FeatureExtractor

Tags: chemistry, machine-learning

"MoleculeFeatures" is one possible Feature Extractor method. What molecule properties does "MoleculeFeatures" entail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `"MoleculeFeatures"` is currently equivalent to the `"MoleculeExtendedConnectivity"` feature extractor plus a dimension reduction step.  I would recommend using one of the named feature extractors

- "MoleculeTopologicalFeatures" (aka RDKit or daylight-like fingerprint)
- "ExtendedConnectivity" - (aka Morgan or ECFP fingerprint)
- "AtomPairs"

Comment: Are there examples of ml applications that use these features?